# Very unstable version after fresh install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I've just installed a Ubuntu 14.04 version on a relatively recent PC : ASUS G10AC.

I've applied all fundamentals from [Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 14.04 & 14.10](https://goo.gl/LxxfxG)

But my installation is quite unstable. I have for example to restart after opening single web links which freeze all my config.

So it is unstable in the sense that if I click on one web link in Chrome that can hang all my config.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop or 14.04 Server?

Comment: It's 14.04 desktop

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop from a usb stick or a dvd drive?

Comment: Also edit your question to include graphic card and driver used. This is the single most common instability factor on any GNU/linux desktop installation.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets redirectet to [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/login?e=2) when clicking on your link? So when I'm not, could you please edit your question and write the correct link.

Comment: Hera are the details of my config (shared from my dropbox in the file config.txt) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sboim6essid01qo/AADElELcWvijAYP3wjphbxBja?dl=0

Comment: Hera are the details of my config in the confix.txt file from my dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8cwtpxxb22uzch/config.txt?dl=0

Comment: Hera are the details of my config in the confix.txt file from my dropbox dropbox.com/s/m8cwtpxxb22uzch/config.txt?dl=0 – Laurent06000

Answer (score 1):

Finally I reverted back to Windows 10 on this PC. Yous can forget this one. Sorry for inconvenience.

Laurent06000